# C++ VS2008 Linker Error (already defined) simply by adding a #include

Tags: visual-c++, dll, mfc, linker, static-libraries

I have an application written in VS2008 C++ that has been working correctly for a long time.
It is comprised of several static lib projects which are all linked into one .exe

During the course of some maintenance, I have added an extra #include to one of the .cpp files in one of the static library projects, resulting in the exe (a separate project) refusing to link. The problem is resolved if I remove the offending #include (and try to re-factor the maintenance change), but clearly something isn't quite right and I need to get to the bottom of it.

The link errors are:

```
Error   3   error LNK2005: "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned int)" (??2@YAPAXI@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(new.obj)   nafxcwd.lib
Error   4   error LNK2005: "void __cdecl operator delete(void *)" (??3@YAXPAX@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dbgdel.obj) nafxcwd.lib
Error   5   error LNK2005: "void __cdecl operator delete[](void *)" (??_V@YAXPAX@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(delete2.obj) nafxcwd.lib
Error   6   fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found Tmtka.exe   1
```

These typically point to inconsistencies in the versions (static vs dynamic) of the CRT library used by the various .lib(s) and the executable. However, all .lib(s) and the executable are consistently built using "/MT" and "Use MFC in a Static Library"

An additional piece of the puzzle, is that when all .lib(s) and the executable are consistently set to "/MD" and "Use MFC in a shared DLL", the problem goes away. However, as we'd ideally like to continue releasing as statically linked (self contained) an application as we can, we want to figure out how to resolve this while continuing to build using "/MT" and "Use MFC in a Static Library".

There are no explicit 3rd party libraries used, but VS2008 may very well be linking to some under the hood that may dynamically link to the CRT or MFC, thus causing this problem. But then why would the problem manifest itself only now, after years of successful operation, by virtue of the simple introduction of this unfortunate #include directive?

Is it an ordering of libraries problem perhaps?

The explicit libraries in "Additional Dependencies" are ordered such that those libraries that depend on others appear first, even if the MSCV linker dosn't supposedly suffer from the problems this is trying to forestall as badly as say gcc supposedly does. But I have a feeling that if this is an ordering problem that manifests itself intermitently it may have more to do with the ordering of under the hood dependencies.

How do I begin trying to figure this out? What tools should I use? I tried depends.exe but it doesn't seem to want to open .lib files (I tried to make sure I understood their dependencies)

Please help...

Comment: Try building with `/VERBOSE:LIB` linker switch - it will tell you which libraries the linker is bringing in. Compare the output when including and not including that header.

Comment: Well, look in the #included file for replacements for operator new and delete.  You don't want them in the Debug build so wrap them with #ifndef DEBUG.

Comment: @HansPassant. Thanks Hans. I should have said, the #include is for a file already included by other compilation units in the same library. It doesn't redefine any memory allocation operators.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik. Thanks Igor. After searching through the explicit libraries I point it to, the linker searches through following list of under the hood libraries in static /MT mode.  For functioning config: DelayImp.lib, libcpmtd.lib, LIBCMTD.lib, OLDNAMES.lib,kernel32.lib. For broken config: DelayImp.lib, libcpmtd.lib, xcwd.lib(this one is different), OLDNAMES.lib, nafxcwd.lib (and here is where it complains about new and delete being already defined). Got somewhere, though not sure what to do with this info. Neither xcwd nor nafxcwd are searched for at all if I don't #include the given file

Comment: @IgorTandetnik. continued... in the new location, and said given included file is already being included by another compilation unit in the same .lib. Not sure why including it in two compilation units would make the linker look for a different set of libraries than if it were only included by one compilation unit.

Comment: I don't know what `xcwd.lib` is. It doesn't appear to be part of MSVC installation (whereas `nafxcwd.lib` is). I don't have this file anywhere on my machine. A Google search found it mentioned once, in conjunction with VC4 compiler. Try to figure out where it came from and what it's doing in your project. I'm pretty sure it wasn't supposed to be there. Try deleting it (after first saving a copy someplace safe) and see what breaks.

Comment: mmm interesting, it is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib\xcwd.lib so seems legit. let me see what happens if I remove it or direct the linker to ignore it

Comment: @IgorTandetnik. So setting the linker ignore xcwd.lib, search list now identical to the working case, up to point where the broken config searches nafxcwd.lib (the working config does not search in this library at all). At that point, it complains again about new and delete being already defined. I make the linker ignore nafxcwd.lib, I get a host of unresolved ATL and AFX symbols.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik.  I suppose I'd like to understand how the linker decides where to search. Both configurations are identical except for the additional #include in the broken config, which points to a file that is nevertheless already included elsewhere. Why does the linker search in different libraries...?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik. And another gem. I've now removed the ignore xcwd.lib from the linker to get things back to how they were when I initially got the problem and although things are still broken in the same way, the linker nevertheless no longer looks for xcwd.lib. It now looks in LIBCMTD.lib (in line with what the working config does). How does the linker decide where to look?

Comment: Re: where linker looks. A library could be explicitly specified on the command line ("Additional Dependencies" setting), or an OBJ file may refer to one. The compiler embeds such reference when it sees `#pragma  comment(lib)` directive. That's how settings like "Use MFC in static/shared library" work: the setting just defines a macro, and somewhere in MFC headers there are `#pragma` directives controlled by those macros. Finally, compiler options `/MT`, `/MD` et al also tell the compiler to tell the linker to link appropriate CRT libraries.

Comment: Now that I think about it, this is perhaps what happens. The offending header defines the same macro that "Use MFC as shared library" defines. If it's included after MFC headers, it doesn't matter. But if it's included before MFC headers, then it triggers a `#pragma` that links to MFC DLL, and now you have a conflict between MFC static and dynamic libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. The problem arose when I compiled my project with MFC static linked, and I added another lib to my project that also used MFC static linked.  Changing the C++ project option for Precompiled Headers to /Yu (**using precompiled headers**) did the magic.